# query mongodb inside nested array of objects

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have entry in a collection like this one:

```
{
   "overlaps": [
      {"BB1": "itemA", "iou": 0.1, "BB2": "itemB"},
      {"BB1": "itemB", "iou": 0.45, "BB2": "itemC"}
   ],
   "elemID": 1,
   "otherfield2": "whateverelse"
}
```

I want to find entries that have element in the overlap array  where overlaps.BB1:"itemA" and overlaps.BB2:"itemC". But for the same element in the overlaps array.

For instance, the example given here should not be retrieved, because I have overlaps.BB1:"itemA" and overlaps.BB2:"itemC", but not in the same element.

A valid element would be:

```
{
   "overlaps": [
      {"BB1": "itemA", "iou": 0.1, "BB2": "itemC"},
      {"BB1": "itemB", "iou": 0.45, "BB2": "itemC"}
   ],
   "elemID": 2,
   "otherfield2": "whateverelse"
}
```

I have tried this but does not work

```
cursor = record1.find({"$and": [{"overlaps.BB1":"itemA"},{"overlaps.BB2":"itemC"}]})
```

How can I make this work? Or should I change my data structure in order to be able to perform such queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$elemMatch` to get the result

```
db.collection.find({
  overlaps: {
    $elemMatch: {
      BB1: "itemA",
      BB2: "itemC"
    }
  }
})
```